# WebScraping with Selenium: click and open buttons

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape this website using Python and Selenium: https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-anywhere/20210801,20210801

I want to click and open each single travel box (the box with the city's name and the flight's price, when you click on it you obtain more details).

I don't figure out why my code doesn't work, I don't obtain any errors, just nothing.

To handle the cookies I'm using the first part of code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.maximize_window()
wd.implicitly_wait(30)
wd.get("https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-anywhere/20210810,20210810")
wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 20)
try:
    if(len(wd.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id$='accept']"))) > 0:
        print("click privacy")
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id$='accept']"))).click()
    else:
        print("button not find")
except:
    print("error")
    pass

import time
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.get("https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-anywhere/20210810,20210810")
time.sleep(5)
if (len(wd.find_elements_by_id("_eY._iwG._ihs._irH")) > 0):
  print("Click travel box")
  wd.find_elements_by_id("_eY._iwG._ihs._irH")[0].click()
```

Comment: you got any error and can you let us know what is travel box?

Comment: I've edited the question with the part of code that I'm using to manage the cookies.  Thanks

Comment: Anything printed on the console? Any of those `print` statements? Please post your output too

Comment: Sometimes I obtain "click privacy", sometimes "button not find". Then nothing.